# VS2008 setup project installing extra dependency files

Tags: visual-studio, installation

In `VS2008` I have a setup project which installs the Primary Output of one app to the application folder, and the `Primary Output` of class library project into a subfolder of the application directory.

Both projects reference several third-party assemblies (some `DevExpress` **UI** controls).

When I install the application, the subfolder is successfully created and the class library assembly is correctly put there.  However, all the third-party assemblies are duplicated to this folder as well (they are in the main application folder *and* the subfolder).

One other completely bizarre behavior (IMO) is that if I delete the extra assemblies manually from the subfolder, then I run the executable in the app folder, the deleted assemblies get copied to the subfolder again.

I then modified the setup project to only install the class library assembly from its Debug folder (as opposed to the `Primary Output`).  When I install the app the `DevExpress` DLLs are *still* going to both folders.  (However, if I delete the extra assemblies and run the executable the extra dependencies do not reappear this time.)

What's going on here?  All I want is the class libraries I add to the `Setup Project` to appear in the subfolder, and the executable and all the dependencies to be in the Application folder.

Whats really driving me batty is I migrated this solution from `VS2005` and I never had this problem before.  Is there a setting in `VS2008` at that causes this?